# Incorrect time in created_at column - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with timestamps column (created_at and updated_at) in mySql database. I am using laravel version 5.4 and php 7.0.

I happened to notice that it is adding incorrect time to this particular column.

For example: A record was actually added at 9:01 AM, but the created_at column has 9:05 AM. This is not always, happens occasionally. (For 1 in 20 database entries).

Comment: Maybe the machine hosting the mySql server is not synchronized with the machine hosting the web server?

Comment: Try using `created_at->format('H:i a')`;

Comment: @Amarnasan, It is synchronized. This is an occasional behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i just hope is does not occur when running project locally. It happen when hosted, the n it depends on where your server is running.

Comment: Even on the server, it is occasional. Not always this happens. I started noticing this behavior after I did php artisan down and then  php artisan up after about one hour.

Comment: This is not even close to an answer, rather a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone in `config/app.php` file

Find

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'Asia/Colombo'),
```

you can set any timezone based on your project

You can convert time from a different timezone

From `Asia/Colombo` to `America/New_York`

```
$model->updated_at->timezone('America/New_York')->format('d-m-Y h:i A');
```

Comment: I don't think this is a timezone issue. It is adding as 9.05 AM when the time really is 9.01 AM. This is occasional. All other times created_at timestamp is updated correctly according to the current time.

Comment: your site/database is hosted or you are using in local machine?

Comment: Hosted on server

Comment: you can update the config file as my answer. it should work

Comment: in your app, created_at and updated_at time will save in UTC time. you can set the particular timezone

Comment: Changed  the timezone and checked. Still no luck. Cron job is supposed to run every 5 minutes. Today suddenly a couple of hours back, it ran 5 times at once. Then again it was back to normal.